# Create multiple custom-elements with Svelte and Rollup in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, rollupjs, svelte

I'm trying to create multiple web-custom elements using Svelte and Rollup inside the one project.

The idea is to have a folder structure like this

```
web-components
    component-1
        index.svelte
    component-2
        index.svelte
```

This should the be "looped" by Rollup and create a set of JS files

```
publish
    component-1.js
    component-2.js
```

Each of the svelte components will be standalone/autonomous, and I might also create other components using other technologies as well. (React/Vanilla.js/lit.hmtl/stencil)

I'm working in Visual Studio, and the examples for doing these things is quite sparse.. Anyone that can direct me to a good example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not have a current example for what you are trying to do, but having done something similar this seems to be an approach worth trying:

Your `rollup.config.js` file can, instead of a single object, return an array:

```
export default [
 { configuration for component 1 },
 { configuration for component 2 }
];
```

Since each configuration would have some duplication (plugins, format, ...) it's probably best to abstract those out:

```
const toRollupConfig = ({ src, dest }) = {
  /// Rollup Configuration
};

export default [
  toRollupConfig({ 
    src: './web-components/component-1/index.svelte', 
    dest: './publish/component-1.js' 
  }),
  toRollupConfig({ 
    src: './web-components/component-2/index.svelte', 
    dest: './publish/component-2.js' 
  }),
];
```

Since this would require you make a line for each component, you could go a step further and fetch all your `.svelte` files using something like `glob` or similar and map the result with `toRollupConfig` given you the final code:

```
const GetComponents = (srcDir, destDir) => {
  // Get the files and return for each an object of the form { src, dest }
};

const toRollupConfig = ({ src, dest }) = {
  /// Rollup Configuration
};

export default GetComponents('./web-components/','./publish').map(toRollupConfig);
```

Comment: Super, I wil check it out. Thanks a lot